# can sender send 2 amounts to single recipient in single transaction?

Tags: transactions, sending, sendtoaddress

I am working on web-app that needs to send money to customer's addresses.

i am trying find out if is it possible to ,
Bitcoin sender to send 2 or more amounts to single address in single transaction ?

e.g.

```
Transaction 1->
               sender1 -> (20 satoshis)-> receiver 1
                       -> (40 satoshis)-> receiver 1
```

Is this possible ?

i know i can add both amounts and do single transaction. but i would like to know can this be doable ?

Comment: note that transactions with any output under 546 satoshis will not be relayed (the rules are a bit more complex, but for a standard tx, that's the threshold).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This sort of transaction is doable in bitcoin.

A point which I would like ot highlight is that transaction fees in bitcoin are proportional to the transaction size in bytes(and not the amount being sent). So, splitting the amount into 2 outputs will cost you more than combining the outputs.

Comment: are there any examples of this type ? on prolly blockchain ? how can i find them ? thanks

Comment: There is nothing special about having the same address appear in two different outputs. This example shows simple multiple outputs in a transaction, you would instead have same pubkeyhash in 2 outputs https://blockchain.info/tx/be4d79051eefbb70c5269e7f2410d695cd9a0cddb583e6ec18b29bbc77f8fc14?show_adv=true.